# Make alert/popup box in unity game for android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make a game, for which I completed a whole framework and other stuff, but GUI programming is painful. I want to create a box as shown in the picture below. I tried to do it so many times, but every time it's just not working at all.

I have done many things for it with `GUI.BOX`, `GUI.DrawTexture`, `GUI.Window` and tried to make android plugin code, too.

I want to make my box like this image:

[image: example image]

```
void OnGUI()
{
    GUI.BeginGroup(new Rect(10, Screen.height / 2 - 50, Screen.width - 20, hintTexture.height));
    GUI.DrawTexture(new Rect(10,Screen.height /2 - 50,Screen.width -20 , hintTexture.height),hintTexture);
    GUI.Label(new Rect(20, Screen.height / 2 - 50, Screen.width - 20, 50), "Are you sure want to Quit?", noGUIStyle);
    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, Screen.height / 2, Screen.width - 20, yesBtn.height), yesBtn,noGUIStyle))
    {
        Application.Quit();
    }

    if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, Screen.height / 2, Screen.width - 20, noBtn.height), noBtn,noGUIStyle))
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    GUI.EndGroup();
}
```

For Unity Android :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would strongly suggest you look into [NGUI](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/2413), [2D Toolkit](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/#/content/908) or any other GUI framework that is currently in the [Asset Store](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/). [Prime31's UIToolkit](https://github.com/oddgames/UIToolkit) is even free and opensource.

Most, if not all, provide a way to design a dialog in a WYSIWYG fashion and also take care of multiple resolutions, anchoring, scaling, etc.

Also, Unity's OnGUI is generally not recommended for heavy UI, especially for mobile devices, since it has serious performance issues. Although, that depends on the complexity of your UI and might not be the case.